# Bug that I can't understand and fix in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

To put in context I am building an app as an exercise in a course to program in react native and we are learning Redux

For me everything is fine but I have doubts in two parts in the index of the scene where the application is seen in this case welcome / index.js there is a line that is for 'useSelector' and another is in the reduce of recipe that if the data is well linked because it throws me an error.

"ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'store.getState')"

I share the different components of the redux.
Everything is in a store folder and everything is modulated

store/reduce

store/reduce/index.js

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";

import { recipesReducer } from "./reducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  recipes: recipesReducer
});

export default createStore(rootReducer);
```

store/reducer/recipes.reducer.js

```
import {recipeTypes} from '../types';
import {recipes} from '../../data';

const { SELECT_RECIPE } = recipeTypes;

const initialState = {
  recipes: recipes,
  selectedRecipe: null
}

const recipesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {  
  switch(action.type) {
    case SELECT_RECIPE:
      const indexRecipe = state.recipes.findIndex(
        (recipe) => recipe.id === action.recipeId
      );
      if(indexRecipe === -1) return state;
        return {
          ...state,
          selectedRecipe: state.recipes[indexRecipe]
        }
      default:
        return state;
  }
}
export default recipesReducer;
```

store/reduce/index.js

```
export {default as recipesReducer} from './recipes.reducer';
```

store/types/index.js

```
export * from './recipes.types';
```

store/types/recipes.type.js

```
   export const recipeTypes = {
  SELECT_RECIPE: 'SELECT_RECIPE',
}
```

store/action/recipes.action.js

```
import { recipeTypes } from '../types';

const { SELECT_RECIPE } = recipeTypes;

    export const selectRecipe = (id) => {
      return {
        type: SELECT_RECIPE,
        recipeId: id,
      };
    }
```

store/action/index.js

```
export * from './repice.action';
```

welcome/index

```
import {Button, CardsRecipes, MenuAlt, Pickers, TT} from '../../components';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import Color from '../../constants/colors';
import { recipe } from '../../data';
import { selectRecipe } from '../../store/action';

const Welcome= ({navigation, route}) => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const recipe = useSelector(state => state.recipe.recipe);

  const onSelected = (item) => {
    dispatch(selectRecipe(item.id));
    navigation.navigate('Recipe');
  }  

  const renderItem = ({item}) => <CardsRecipes item={item} onSelected={onSelected(item)} />

  return ( 
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MenuAlt title = {'Recetas'} />
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text style= {styles.text}>Bienvenido a la App de Recetas de Cocina</Text>
      </View>
      <View style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data= {recipe}
        renderItem = {renderItem}
        keyExtractor = {item => item.id}
      />
      
    </View >

  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Color.primary,
    color: Color.letter,     
    fontFamily: 'Lato-Regular',
  },
  
  textContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  text: {
    color: Color.letter,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },

  buttonContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    height: 33,
  },

});

export default Welcome;
```

app.js

```
import {ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import AppNavigator from './navigation';
import Color  from './constants/colors';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { store } from './store';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

export default function App() {

  //useState
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
  const [order, setOrder] = useState([]);

  //funciones


  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    'Lato-Regular': require('./assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf'),
    'Lato-Bold': require('./assets/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf'),
    'Lato-Light': require('./assets/fonts/Lato-Light.ttf'),
    'Lato-Italic': require('./assets/fonts/Lato-Italic.ttf'),
    'Lato-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Lato-Black.ttf'),
  });

  if(!loaded) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.containerLoader}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={Color.letter} />  
      </View>
    )
  }
  
  const onSelectedEnlarge = ( select, order ) => {
    setOrder(order)
    setSelected(select);
  };
/*  
  let content = <Super onSelectedEnlarge={onSelectedEnlarge} object = {order}/>;
  
  if (!selected) {
    content = <Super onSelectedEnlarge={onSelectedEnlarge} object = {order}/>;
  }
  else
  {
    content = <ListSuper onSelectedEnlarge={onSelectedEnlarge} object = {order}/>;
  }
*/
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppNavigator/>
    </Provider>
  ); 
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Color.primary,
    color: Color.letter,     
    fontFamily: 'Lato-Regular',
  }, 

});
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Shouldn't it be? `useSelector(state => state.recipes)`?

Comment: follow the same error

Comment: I have doubts about those same lines where do you get categories from?

Comment: Do you export `store` as a named variable from `./store/index.js`? I think this is a problem with something not being exported. Maybe it exports default and not named.

Comment: i solver I write incorrect in app.js import store  from './store';  and welcome in   const recipe = useSelector(state => state.recipes.recipes)  thank